# How to extend default “Backtesting range” for Strategy Tester of TradingView

Tags: date-range, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

There is a heap of posts on how to set a specific time interval (Date Range) in PineScript for Strategy Tester. But it works only within a default time interval specified by TradinView. I don’t find how to **extend the default time interval** (ca. 6500 candles from the present to the past) for particular strategies. It is possible at all??
[Strategy Tester - Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CSdJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is the "Deep Backtesting" mode enabled for **TradingView Premium users only** allowing to backtest more than 20K candles

Other than that, the number of historical bars depends on your TradingView account type
More informations here: https://www.tradingview.com/gopro in the "Historical bars available" section